# Публикация приложения в azure

Tags: azure

Изучаю azure, возникла такая проблема сделал авторизацию по oauth2 и для меня все нормально работает, но если другой пользователь хочет авторизовать выбивает ошибку:

```
access_denied
AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application
```

Я так понимаю мое приложения нужно опубликовать для всех пользователей? можете подсказать куда дальше двигаться?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, вам нужно либо добавить пользователей приложения в Users and Groups в профиле приложения в Azure Active Directory.

Либо отключить опцию User Assignment Required и сделать приложение доступным для всех пользователей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]